# Designing a turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

I need help designing a turing machine that will compute the following `f(x) = x mod 3`. I just need help getting started since I am not familiar on how to approach this problem

Comment: In what base (unary/binary/denary/...) is the input? How is the input delimited? How should the output be performed?

Comment: the base should be unary

Comment: Do you want to replace the input with output, or append the output after the input?

Comment: replace the input with the output

Comment: @mcalex I guess the algorithm description will do.

Comment: im trying to do the formal equation

Comment: oh. I can give you the algorithm description, though.

Comment: Also, you should specify all those details (input format, output format, ...) when asking. Always provide enough information so that the question can be answered.

Comment: algorithm description is fine

Comment: for example 5 mod 3 in unary should be like 111110111 Im not sure how the output would look like

Comment: Wait a moment - you want `x mod y`, not `x mod 3`?

Comment: x mod 3. x can be any number. I was just showing an example

Comment: If `3` is a constant, then why is it a part of the input.

Comment: I thought that was the way it was represented, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracts from the comments:

The input and input is in unary as a string of `1`. Space is `0`. The output should rewrite the input.

The input is {x, 3} with one space between each argument or {x}.

The output is {x mod 3}.

Algorithm:

- Go to the end of the input.
- Remove the second argument.
- While there are at least three symbols in the argument, remove them.

State machine:

- Start: If input is 0, move right and go to "deleting right", else move right.
- Deleting right: If input is 0, move left and go to "finding arg". Else write 0 and move right.
- Finding arg: If input is 0, move left. If input is "start of tape", finish. Else move left and go to state "found 1".
- Found 1: If input is "start of tape", finish. Else move left and go to the state "found 2"
- Found 2: If input is "start of tape", finish. Else and go to the state "deleting right".